# Is it possible to create a custom power plan?

Tags: windows-7, power

I have seen some software that can create and switch automatically between power plans, like TuneUp utilities and Xilisoft Video Converter.

How can I create my own custom power plan in Windows 7 Ultimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can: See detailed [Microsoft post](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/Change-create-or-delete-a-power-plan-scheme). Or just go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options and click "Create a power plan". After that set your preferences for your custom plan.

[image]

Comment: A good answer, but am I correct in that you still have to switch to it manually?  I cannot see a way iTunes or anything else can automatically use a Custom Power Plan.

Comment: You can do everything via command prompt: powercfg /?